# List system properties in WebSphere 7

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I have a running instance of WebSphere Application Server 7 and I need to know the current values of Java System Properties.

Is there any way to get this information?

(I would like to know the least intrusive way, so adding a JSP which prints properties is not considered)

Comment: I know you said... but adding a JSP is very unintrusive :-) Just copy the file out to the correct directory in the `installedApps` hierarchy without even modifying your war. Unless you'll need to be doing this on a regular basis in the future. Just sayin'.

Comment: @dbreaux Thank you for your comment, but I don't have easy access to the file system.

Comment: Fair enough. Can you deploy through the WAS console? If so, you can deploy individual files on top of the deployed WAR. Still don't need to modify the official WAR. You just need to check the values at some point in time?

Comment: @dbreaux It is a production environment, and I would prefer not to ask for a deployment, but it could be an option. You may write an answer with your comments in case I don't find a better alternative.

Comment: I've looked for ways to get this information with wsadmin scripting, but everything I've found seems to only return properties that you've defined yourself through one of the configuration mechanisms, not those implicitly defined by the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to get specific properties by name via `wsadmin` scripting, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent way to list "all" properties.

This may not help you, but in case anyone has a similar need in the future, here's a couple of Jython commands to retrieve one of the standard System properties.

```
jvm = AdminControl.completeObjectName('WebSphere:type=JVM,process=YourServerName,*')
AdminControl.invoke(jvm,'getProperty','user.timezone')
```

Comment: In my case I needed to check java.io.tmpdir, so this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger a thread dump (javacore). It will take a couple of seconds and will be barely noticeable. Thread dump will list all environment properties of JVM in its informative section. Search for flags 1CIENVVARS, 2CIENVVAR as can be seen at snippet below.

```
...
1CIENVVARS     Environment Variables
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2CIENVVAR      _=/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java
2CIENVVAR      LANG=en_US
2CIENVVAR      CONFIG_ROOT=/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Srv02/config
2CIENVVAR      LOGIN=wasadmin
2CIENVVAR      SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
2CIENVVAR      CLCMD_PASSTHRU=1
2CIENVVAR      PATH=/WebSphere/AppServer/java/ibm_bin:/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/:/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/bin:/WebSphere/AppS
...
```

Comment: Although, those aren't System.properties.

Comment: Hmm, that's right dbreaux, I certainly missed that. Coupled with all commandline arguments (-D, -X options) which are also listed at the threaddump, environment properties may provide good insight into JVM, as initial value of system dependent System.properties are derived from environment variables. But one may change system properties once JVM is initialized using System.setProperty, and these are not easy to track down.

Comment: @kurtcebe Those are in fact environment variables, not system properties :(

Answer (score 0):

If you get no better options, deploying a JSP either directly to the filesystem or via the console's single-file deploy should be not too intrusive. Particularly given that you don't have to actually change your built WAR file to deploy an independent JSP on top of it.